# Java - Creating a Calendar without a TimeZone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I would like to start by saying that I've read several threads similar to this one, but none of them really solved my problem.
I would also like to state that I've tried to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `joda.DateTime` without any success.

The problem is the following:

I have a Calendar object that holds the information about a specific date: 2008-04-30T00:00:00Z
When using the `calendar.getTime()` method I can get different results because I know that that method is looking for the local value

Thus:

```
UK: 2008-04-30T01:00:00.000+0100

US: 2008-04-30T20:00:00.000-0400
```

But I would like to get a Date object that holds just the Date and Time values "2008-04-30T00:00:00" ignoring completely any timezone.

How can I do that?

As I mentioned before I tried to use 
`SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")`
 but I always end up with the same results.

Any help would be really appreciated
Cheers.

Comment: Can you provide the example you have tried?

Comment: I've tried the following:
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
sf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
sd.parse(value);    //value is '2008-04-30T00:00:00Z'

Comment: You can't have a Calendar without a TimeZone.  The very notion of a Calendar depends on a timezone, otherwise it's meaningless.

Answer (score 12):

Found out that you can clear the Timezone by using code below:

`Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);`

Comment: this actually helped me - this is really helpful in such application where we need not to care about time zone. In addition to the time zone - we can also clear lot other things like - hours, Minutes , mili seconds - all such fields can be found here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 4):

`Calendars` and `Dates` mean nothing without a `TimeZone`.

Calendars and dates **cannot** exist without a timezone.

You can't `ignore completely any timezone`.

You can create a Calendar for Greenwich Mean Time (offset zero) like this:

```
    TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(zone);
```

This represents a Date/Calendar that is only meaningful in the GMT timezone.

It sounds like you want a timestamp, which represents an instant in time.

Comment: this is shit answer, because you can clearly use date without timezone and then use calendar with cleared time zone info to actually work with values. If your application only exists in one timezone, you can safely ignore timezone. Problem is, that when you get a `Date` value and you are ignoring timezones for that date (you get long value) `Calendar` will be off by your timezone with respect to all operations.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `Calendar` and `Date` objects cannot exist without a time zone.

I believe you may want to use the [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class introduced in Java 8 with the new time API:

```
LocalDateTime literal = LocalDateTime.of(2008, 4, 30, 0, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime parsed = LocalDateTime.parse("2008-04-30T00:00:00"); // ISO-8601 by default
Assert.assertEquals(literal, parsed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a standard constructor for initializing Calendar? What if you used the constructor which allows to specify the time zone and locale?

```
protected Calendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)
```

Comment: I actually tried that way aswell by doing:

CALENDAR.getInstance(TIME_ZONE_UTC, Locale.UK);

but this returns the same value as: UK: 2008-04-30T01:00:00.000+0100

Comment: Every Calendar instance will always have a TimeZone associated with it.  That's how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but still incorrect.

> "When using the calendar.getTime() method I can get different results because I know that that method is looking for the local value"

That is a misconception. getTime() will get the Milliseconds only. Countet as GMT.

ONLY during formatting of the Output the time zone becomes relevant. Sind the original poster did not show the code, it can not be decided, where the error occurs.